# iframes security and implementation

Tags: security, iframe

My questions are regarding iframes and feeding data through a 3d party website.

I've implemented an iframe, which opens a website that is hosted elsewhere. Are there any security concerns that I need to be aware of? The foreign page loads fine, the content displays fine, but there are some JS errors like

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.example.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "http://foreignpage.com". Protocols, domains, and
>   ports must match.

Is it possible for the person on the other side to add some malicious code that loads on my side?

And finally I would like to know if the person will get their Ads revenue if his content is opened from within my iframe.

Comment: See [Understanding 3rd party iframes security?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329269/understanding-3rd-party-iframes-security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've implemented an iframe, which opens a website that is hosted elsewhere. Are there any security concerns that I need to be aware of?

Yes, to a limited degree. Javascript running in a frame can perform some actions that your users may find obnoxious, including:

- Causing the browser to navigate to another page
- Causing the browser to open popup windows
- Running Flash or Java content

You should generally not open frames to pages that you do not trust.

> Is it possible for the person on the other side to add some malicious code that loads on my side?

No, it is not possible. That's what the error message you're seeing (**Blocked** a frame…) is notifying you about.

> And finally I would like to know if the person will get their Ads revenue if his content is opened from within my iframe.

Depends entirely on the advertising network.

Comment: Interesting. I'm reading a lot on the topic. I was curious if it is possible to create a fake page phishing and when that thing loads in my iframe keylog the user's input etc. I'm thinking of putting a warning around the iframe to warn users not to trust/input any details. I'm wondering if stumbleupon has some problems with people who are abusing the service.

Comment: Right, that's the exact sort of thing I'd be worried about - a frame taking over and masquerading as the page that was hosting it.

Comment: do you think i can get around that by somehow disabling all inputs in the iframe window using javascript etc. Any suggestion since I'm worried about that too.